# VB6, MS Access, DAO - Display all records WHERE column-name IS NOT NULL

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao

I need a bit of help with this, so what I am trying to do is to display all records WHERE column-name IS NOT NULL. What I have is:

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sqlStr As String

```
Set WS = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
DbFile = (App.Path & "\mydb.mdb")

strSql = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabaseName"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)
rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
lblResult.Caption = ("cust Name: " & rs!SurName & " cust Surname: " & rs!FirstName)
  rs.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox ("End ")
```

What I have tried is

```
strSql = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabaseName WHERE column-name IS NOT NULL"
```

But I get an error 3131. Any help is appreciated. Also how can I display the result in a ListBox insted of Label.

Comment: Please don't ask double-barreled questions, like "Also how can I display the result in a ListBox insted of Label.". If you want an answer to a second question, ask it properly, and supply the necessary information for us to be able to answer it.

Comment: You haven't specified what column you want to check. SurName and FirstName are two columns, not one.

Comment: Sorry about that, it would be another column in the db called personPresent

Comment: Please don't give us air code like this, but your actual code. There may be problems with reserved words, or other issues that you didn't include in your excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix: enclose column names in square brackets when using special characters, like the `-` substraction operator:

`strSql = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabaseName WHERE [column-name] IS NOT NULL"`

The rest of your SQL seems valid.

If you want a list box with the results of this query as the list, just set its row source equal to this query, and set its row source type equal to Table/Query. No need for any VBA.

If you want to put everything in a label, use:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
  lblResult.Caption = lblResult.Caption & "cust Name: " & rs!SurName & " cust Surname: " & rs!FirstName & VbCrLf
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: This will display only one entry not all.

Comment: Well yes, of course. This code: `Do While Not rs.EOF
lblResult.Caption = ("cust Name: " & rs!SurName & " cust Surname: " & rs!FirstName)
  rs.MoveNext
Loop` is pretty weird and only assigns the latest entry to `lblResult.Caption`

Comment: [column-name] it's only one column, while the OP check on two columns: SurName and FirstName, therefore we can to have SurName = NULL or FirstName =NULL or both of them = NULL.

Comment: I'm only correcting the SQL OP has provided. Don't know exactly what you want to say. Since I don't have the name for both columns, I can't use them in my answer

Comment: Is there a way to display all of the records at the same time which one field is not NULL?

Comment: Yes, obviously. But you have to be clear about what you want exactly. If you just want a listbox filled with a query result, you don't even have to use VBA for that. And since I'm only getting downvoted here, I guess I better just delete my answer.

Comment: Since Do While Not rs.EOF will only display last entry withe the strSql = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabaseName WHERE [personPresent] IS NOT NULL" what needs to be changed so that all of the records (name, surname,) is displayed when it meets criteria from the SELECT statement.